# Is there always a subsequence, whose intersection has a positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have the following problem:

> A number $0<C<1$ is given. On the interval $[0,1]$ there is a sequence of
> compacts with measures at least $C$. Is it true that there is always a
> subsequence, whose intersection has a positive measure?

I took some examples:  $$a_n = \left[\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\right]$$
The measure here is Lebesgue measure, that means:

$\mu([a, b]) = b-a$, if $b \geq a$

$\mu([a, b]) = 0$, if $b \leq a$

Here $C = \frac{1}{2}$.

But it seems here the intersection of each subsequence has the positive measure.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think taking as the $k$-th compact the closure of the set of all reals whose binary representation at position $k$ equals $0$ (measure $1/2$) would not provide such a sequence because adding a new set to the intersection would always halve its measure.

Comment: I was just about to post exactly that example as an answer. You should - you might say what you said and add that  $K_n=\bigcup_{j=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\left[\frac{2j}{2^n},\frac{2j+1}{2^{n}}\right]$ just to nail things down...

Comment: I see now... We have here that each intersection will only contain points which have the form $\frac{1}{2^n}$ that means that intersection will have the zero measure as a sum of measure of such points. Thank you!